# Paypal IPN with uncompleted checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am aware of how to use paypal IPN to set an inventory after checkout has been completed, but there is one part of IPN I can not figure out.

When the user clicks "checkout with paypal" on the website, I would like to set the contents of the cart to "reserved" so that they are temporarily removed from inventory. Then, after a successful checkout, I will use IPN to permanently remove these items from the inventory. HOWEVER, if the user decides not to follow through with the paypal payment, my items are left in "reserved" limbo. IPN will not, as far as I know, report back to the site that the checkout session timed out or was terminated.

How can I get my inventory out of reserved and back on the site if a user bails out during paypal checkout, or walks away from their computer and lets the checkout session timeout?

Comment: I suggest using a cron job. Check every minute or so for reserved items that have gone stale and remove them from the inventory. After so long, you can assume they haven't paid. Even PayPal enforces a session timeout after a reasonable amount of time for users that have been idle on their payment pages.

Comment: @josh Is that the only way? My understanding of cron jobs is limited, and I have been warned to use them as little as possible.

Comment: This is just one solution, and one that I've personally implemented. Can you provide a link that warns against cron jobs? If you don't want to execute the cron jobs on your server, here is a service that provides the scheduling for you. http://scheduler.codeeffects.com/

Comment: @josh Thanks for the info. Any chance you know how long it takes for a PayPal checkout to time out? I obviously would want to set up a cron job to check an amount of time longer than the payPal checkout session.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, and cannot readily find any documentation on how long until a session timeout occurs. However, this is easily testable. I would go through the motions of your checkout and before paying with your sandbox account, refresh on the PayPal page every couple minutes to several minutes until you receive the timeout. I doubt it is longer than 5-10 minutes anyway.

Comment: I'm still curious as to whether there is a better solution for this, though. I deal with PayPal on a weekly basis.

Comment: @josh Yea, maybe I am missing something, but it seems like such an obvious feature that paypal should have. If it is completed, send a completed notification. If it times out, send a timed out notification. If it is cancelled, send a cancelled notification. These seem like the basics!